# A French registered car in the UK caught up in travel restrictions with owner now out of the UK

Tags: uk, eu, automobiles

A person had  traveled from France by car to visit relatives in the UK and then had to fly out to Ireland on a family medical emergency ( an expected short duration. ) leaving their French registered car parked up on the road in the UK. COVID travel restrictions then came in both in Ireland and UK forcing the person to remain outside of the UK.
Is there anyway that the French registered car could be moved to a safe location legally when the owner who is not UK national is outside of the UK?

Comment: I'm not sure that the fact that car is registered in France or that the owner isn't a UK citizen make much difference.  Apart from the fact a UK citizen would probably be able to return to the UK more easily.

Answer (score 6):

The owner (now in Ireland) could send the keys by courier (FedEx, UPS, DHL, *et al*) to a friend, or their aforementioned relatives, in the UK and have them drive the car to a safe location.

Comment: Of course one needs to make sure this is an allowed activity during lockdown.

Comment: Insurance would also be a concern.  The person doing the driving would need to be insured to drive this car, most likely via some sort of open drive policy or with more difficulty by having the car owner add them to their insurance policy.

Comment: There's also a lively market in short-term motor vehicle insurance in the UK.  A quick web search will turn up a number of providers who will do you a one-day policy for not very much money, which the friend could ask the owner to reimburse.